# Why is my button isn't working - Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm making a game on unity and i don't know why but my button "Upgrade" doesn't work, i can't click it, i searched for solutions and here is what i tried :

- check if any UI is blocking the way
- check if i had "interactable" and "raycast target" activated
- check if i had an event system

maybe it is from the physics settings in Edit -> project settings -> physics
because i had to deactivate some things for other stuff, but i think i already tried to reactivate all to see what it did.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGhEw.png

here is the project in version 2020.3.33f1 if you want to try something :

https://www.mediafire.com/file/6o17nul40eqtlu9/Mini_RPG.zip/file

Comment: Why is the **EventSystem** a child of **Canvas**? Try moving it outside

Comment: Please don’t just have pictures of code and screens

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that `EventSystem` should be outside of `Canvas`.
It also may be the fact that the button does not have an `OnClick` event property set, unless you are setting it through code.

Comment: hi, i already tried that, it doesn't work. thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can't put a button on a image (set it as his child), i replaced the image by a pannel and it works.